# encapsulate an old buffer in a new one

Tags: c#, flatbuffers

So I have this sort of scheme:

```
table Request {
  a:Sample;
  b:Sample;
}
```

Where table Sample has multiple string vectors and instances of it are pretty big.
I have a lot of files on my filesystem with Sample instances, which took me some time to create.
Now I want to take 2 files at random, read them into memory and create a new Request which encapsulates them.

I'm working with c# and this line works:

```
var a = Sample.GetRootAsSample(new ByteBuffer(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathToA))); 
var b = Sample.GetRootAsSample(new ByteBuffer(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathTob)));
```

but I can't seem to find a way to just reference them in a new Request instance.
I need some way of adding those buffers as is to a new builder and then pass their Offset to the new Request all in the same builder.
Building them all over again in a new builder wouldn't be efficient.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to deep-copy a table automatically in C#. Since tables may refer to all sorts of locations in the buffer, this is not a trivial operation, which requires either special purpose code generation or reflection.

There's a `CopyTable` in C++ using reflection. This could be ported to C# or called from C#.

An alternative is to include the existing buffers in the new table in binary form, i.e. make `a` and `b` a vector of ubytes. It means you have to call `GetRootAs` on them to access them, but this is all still very efficient.